# Display lists of list items based on similar dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Currently I have this list:

[image]
As you can see these items have the same date, `21/09`. And when a list item has the same date (`yyyy/mm/dd`) I want it to look like this:

(sorry for my drawing)

[image]

I want to group items that has the same date under a header that tells their common date.

I've been trying to tackle this idea for a while now, but I can't get started. Every time I come up with something it doesn't work (sad I know).

I think I first need to get all events items date in the format `yyyy/mm/dd` and then somehow check if evens on that date contains one or more events. And if they do, they'll get a header with their date and all of the events will be displayed below. Otherwise nothing will be shown.

If you have any tips please let me know!!

Thanks for reading.

### Edit

So the parent component that hold all these list is **dash.js**:

```
events
  .slice(-this.state.showCount)
  .reverse()
  .map((event, i) => {
    var driver = event.driver ? keyedDrivers[event.driver] : false
    var carrier = driver ? keyedCarriers[driver.carrier] : false
    var customer = event.customer
      ? keyedCustomers[event.customer]
      : false

    return (
      <div key={i}>
        <EventItem // This is the list item
          event={event}
          customer={customer}
          carrier={carrier}
          driver={driver}
          lock={keyedLocks[event.unit] || { address: {} }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  })
```

And inside of `EventItem` I simply use all of the props I passed to `EventItem` to display a list.

Also, it's the **event object** that contains the date:

#### A event object:

```
_id: ObjectId("12345")
customer: ObjectId("54321")
timestamp: 2017-08-25T12:04:14.001Z
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is probably to convert your one input list into a list of groups (by date)

```
const input = [{date: '21/09'}, {date: '21/09'},
               {date: '22/09'}, {date: '23/09'},
               {date: '24/09'}, {date: '24/09'}]
```

Now you can `reduce` this from a list, into an objet keyed by dates

```
const output = input.reduce((dates, item) => {
    if (dates[item.date]) {
        dates[item.date].push(item)
    } else {
        dates[item.date] = [item]
    }

    return dates
}, {})

// returns

{
  '21/09': [
    { date: '21/09' },
    { date: '21/09' },
  ],
  '22/09': [{ date: '22/09' }],
  '23/09': [{ date: '23/09' }],
  '24/09': [
    { date: '24/09' },
    { date: '24/09' },
  ]
}
```

You can then do

```
Object.keys(output).map(date => (
  <div key={date}>
    <Heading>{date}</Heading>
    {output[date].map(item => (
      <Item>
      ...
      </Item>
    ))}
  </div>
))
```

There's plenty you can to do tidy up that code, but hopefully it's enough to get started

Answer (score 1):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com) has a method called [`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy). I think you can make use of it. There are also methods you can use without a third party library.

**Example**

```
let eventsGroups = _.groupBy(events, (event) => moment(event.timestamp).format('YYYY/MM/DD'))

renderEvents() {
  return Object.keys(eventsGroups).map((groupName) => {
    return (
      <div>
        { renderHeader(groupName) }
        { renderEvents(eventsGroups[groupName]) }
      </div>
    )
  });
}

renderHeader(groupName) {
  return <h1>{groupName}</h1>
}

renderEvents(events) {
  return events.map((event) => {
    return <EventItem event={event} />
  })
}
```

Comment: Really cool stuff, thanks! I tried it and I can see how it groups the events into objects by the dates. Now I just wonder how I can make use of it to display the date as a header and it's events underneath.

Comment: @MartinNordström updated answer with a bit more code. Hope it will be more clear.

Comment: Yes, you are being very clear. Just wondering how I should implement it with my code (pretty nooby coder here, sorry!)

Comment: It's ok but I'm sorry that I can't help you with that. That would need a really long and detailed answer. Try to parse my answer and understand what I'm doing piece by piece. With that I'm sure you can implement it by yourself. You got this far right, the rest should be fine.